# Exit nicely from a Bash script

Tags: bash

I'm implementing the logging solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655905/logging-blocks-of-code-to-log-files-in-bash/6685244#6685244), and I don't know if the following lines are *required* whenever I exit the parent Bash process/script:

```
if [ -n "$teepid" ]; then
    exec 1>&- 2>&-  # Close file descriptors to signal EOF to the `tee`
                    # command in the background process
    wait $teepid # Wait for background process to exit
fi
```

Those lines can be found in the `log()` function and in the end of the script. I know that they're *required* in the `log()` function, but are they *required* at the end of the script?

In other words: Would my background job exit nicely without having the aforementioned code written before every `exit` command in my parent process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process identified by PID `$teepid` is backgrounded using `&`.  If you exit without waiting for that PID to finish, the only bad thing that will happen is the same thing that happens if you use `&` in the shell.  You'll hit [Enter] at some later point and get pestered with a `[1] {pid} exited` (or something similar, can't remember precisely now) message before your next prompt line is displayed.

Comment: "If you exit without waiting for that PID to finish, the only bad thing that will happen is the same thing that happens if you use & in the shell." - What it means?

Comment: Try entering `echo "hello" &` from a shell prompt, hit ENTER twice, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Now I understand. So it's safe to remove those lines from the end of the script?

Comment: Sure, but you'll get that side effect if you run it from an interactive prompt.

Comment: Sorry to come to the party late (and uninvited), but I believe you’re mistaken.  In my experience, processes are aware of only their own children.  If a shell script detaches a subprocess, the script’s parent process (commonly an interactive shell) has no knowledge of that (sub)process, and will not know when it terminates.

Comment: You can demonstrate this quickly and easily by typing `(echo "hello" &)` –– the parentheses force the creation of a new process even before the `echo "hello" &` is interpreted, and then that, of course, forks a process at yet another level –– simulating the scenario of a script starting an asynchronous subprocess.  Another good illustration: `(sleep 42 &)` and then `wait` –– you’ll get your shell prompt back immediately, but a `ps` will show that the `sleep` is still in the background.

Comment: The problem/risk, however, that if this logging script doesn’t wait for the `tee` processes to finish, then you might get your shell prompt back before the `tee` finishes, and so you might get output from the `tee` (which is output from the script) displayed after the shell prompt is displayed.  If it’s more than a line or two, it’s very easy for the user not to see the shell prompt, and therefore to assume that the script is still running, when, in fact, it is done.